# Swift - Multiple URL Request - Code To Refactor and To Reuse

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest, urlsession

I'm new to Swift and I am trying to refactor my URL Post requests. I have multiple URL POST requests inside the same View Controller like this. Everything works fine but it seems to me that there is a lot of repetitive code that could be reused. Particularly, I don't know how to pass/handle different Data Models that should be used in parseRequest1 and parseRequest2. I also read that there should be only one session used for URL requests within the same project. Any help would be greatly appreciate it!

```
func request1() {        
    let parameters = [...//some parameters to send]
    guard let url = URL(string: "https//www.....") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let parametersToSend = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) 
       else {
         print("Error")
         return
       }
    request.httpBody = parametersToSend
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
       if let safeData = data {
          self.parseRequest1(data: safeData)
        }
   }.resume()
}

func parseRequest1(data: Data){
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
      let decodedData = try decoder.decode(DataModelForRequest1.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.performAction1(request1Result)
        }
    } catch {
       print(error)
    }
}
```

Then I have another URL request request2 which is almost identical except the parameters, and model to be used for decoding and action inside parseRequest2.

```
func request2() {        
        let parameters = [...//some parameters to send]
        guard let url = URL(string: "https//www.....") else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let parametersToSend = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) 
           else {
             print("Error")
             return
           }
        request.httpBody = parametersToSend
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
           if let safeData = data {
              self.parseRequest2(data: safeData)
            }
       }.resume()
    }

    func parseRequest2(data: Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode(DataModelForRequest2.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.performAction2(request2Result)
            }
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only differences seem to be:

- request parameters
- type of model returned
- the action you do after the response is received

This means that we can write this as one single method taking the above three values as parameters:

```
func request<T: Codable>(modelType: T.Type, parameters: [String: Any], completion: (T) -> Void) {

    func parseResponse(data: Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              completion(decodedData)
            }
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
    } 

    guard let url = URL(string: "https//www.....") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let parametersToSend = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) 
       else {
         print("Error")
         return
       }
    request.httpBody = parametersToSend
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
       if let safeData = data {
          parseResponse(data: safeData)
        }
   }.resume()
}
```

You can then call this method with the appropriate parameters as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks! How would I implement the Delegate for the parseResponse method? 
     `protocol DownloadManagerDelegate {
        func didUpdateData<T: Codable>(modelType: T.Type, downloadedData: T.Type)
     }`

Comment: @Luke I don't understand. How is delegate related to the code in the question? Note that the `parseResponse` in my answer corresponds to your `parseRequest` method.  I renamed it because I didn't think `parseRequest` was a good name. Did you confuse it with some other `parseResponse` in your code?

Comment: See I am trying to return parseResponse back to the VC that called func Request. I though that i should return it via a delegate (instead of the parseResponse) `self.delegate?.didUpdateData(modelType: modelType, downloadedData: downloadedData)`. Sorry I'm kind of new to Swift so I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I posted this new question that has more details of what I have now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579710/swift-reusable-url-request-with-delegates

Comment: @Luke I'm guessing you decided to do something else at some point between asking this question and now? I will try to answer the other question when I have time. In the meantime, does my answer answer _this_ question?